# Accessing $_GET and $_POST query string or form value equivalents in Python

Tags: python, environment-variables, http-post, http-get

In PHP, I can retrieve the value in a query string like so:

So, if the request URI is http://example.com/index.php?foo=bar

```
<?php echo $_GET['foo']; //bar ?>
```

How can I emulate the above code in Python? (and not using a heavy web framework)

I cannot find simple documentation for the easiest way to do this in Python. Is there a standard Python library for handling incoming HTTP requests? I know Python is not a templating language, but its wide usage on the web suggests there should be a simple way of handling this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the web frameworks do it differently. As you say, Python is not a templating language, so there is no automatic way to handle HTTP requests.

There is a [`cgi` module](http://docs.python.org/library/cgi.html#module-cgi) which is part of the standard library, and which you can use to access POSTed data via `cgi.FieldStorage()` - but serving an app via standard CGI is horribly inefficient and only suitable for very small-scale stuff.

A much better idea is to use a simple WSGI framework (WSGI is the standard for serving web applications with Python). There are quite a few - my current favourite is [flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) although I hear good things about [bottle](http://bottle.paws.de/docs/dev/index.html) too.

Comment: I can't quite decipher flask. How would you implement the above code in flask?

Comment: The Flask docs have [a good example here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#the-request-object).

Comment: What is the equivalent of using PHP's `$href = $_GET['cid'];` in `WSGI`?    I am using `Bottle`.

Answer (score 0):

Your "non heavy web framework" should typically pass a request parameter to you, and you can access the get strings from the `request.GET` or something to that effect.